# 2003 Ford Escape XLT 2.0L 4 cyl

Tags: ford, rpm, escape

My RPM's were staying crazy high ....4k-5k switching gears Throttle body was in terrible shape and clearly sticking.
I had a new one put in along with a new IAC valve. Also found out my throttle cable was bent and frayed. Replaced it.
My clutch failed (180k on car) and had it replaced a couple days ago.

I did the relearn and watched the parked in idle rpm settle in at about 500-550, which seems a little on the low side for this vehicle.

Problem is when I get my RPMs going up to the point where I want to move up a gear, they stick, and then will return to normal after a 1-2 seconds.
It reminds me of when you are driving an automatic transmission and you can feel the rpm's "settle in" to the new gear ---- I will be at 40mph for example, and
when the rpms's get to about 3k, I can let my foot off gas (with car in gear) and it's like cruise control, sometimes even to the point where it is accelerating the car even more-- then the rpms go back to normal and I can throw it into neutral without a problem.

Edit:
Drove around during lunch and it's getting more aggressive. Just accelerating on it's own every gear - and if I force it into neutral while it's doing this, the RPMS go to 4k+ for about a 2nd before going to normal. ???

Comment: What's the commanded IAC PID look like? Did you reset the Keep Alive Memory? If you move the throttle by hand does the cable seem to bind?

Comment: Is the replacement IAC Motorcraft or aftermarket?

Comment: It sounds like things are still binding for the throttle body. I would bet Ben is dead on it, like always.

Comment: This is the throttle body I bought:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ees5M.png)

We did the relearn where you drain the battery then restart and let idle for 15-20 min.  I don't have any actual computer readouts.  It's amazing how a new throttle body could have a similar issue as the old dirty one. What causes this binding you are talking about?  It's a new throttle cable too.